# Combine values in column

Tags: ssrs-tablix

Please see the structure of report below:

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Now, I want to combine the column New Week Status which has values Current Full Week and Previous Full Week.

So I want my final output to look like:

[image]

Group on:

[image]

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: What have you already tried and what problem(s) did you experience? Looks like you just need a calculated field or expression which selects either the "Current Full Week" value or the "Previous Full Week" value depending on the `Full_Date`, or just based on which is present, then you can delete your `New Week Status1` column and put that calculate field or expression into the colour-coded cells.

Comment: On the RestuarantName group, I added a new group of NewWeekStatus (please see in the original question last screenshot) and then wrote an expression in Visibility of Restaurant group =IIF((SUM(Fields!Conditi.Value) >= 3 and Fields!New_Week_Status.Value = "Current Full Week") OR (SUM(Fields!Conditi.Value) >= 5), False, True). Now as group on is added the column for Current Full Week and Previous Full Week comes on different lines. If I remove the group on, the first condition for my formula doesnt work. If you have any queries, I am happy to answer and give you more detailed explanation

Comment: Maybe you could just provide a sample dataset so we can try this out ourselves more easily?